# How to format date from Mongodb using react

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I have  `2005-12-03T18:30:00.000Z` this format of date in mongodb.I am using react for frontend .
The problem is i want to display date in dd/mm/yy format .How i can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you get the date from MongoDB and then save in the state, then next in your code you can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) date library, then simply format the date to `dd/mm/yy` like:

```js
const dateFromDB = '2005-12-03T18:30:00.000Z'
const formattedDate = moment(dateFromDB).utc().format('DD/MM/YY')

console.log( 'Date From DB:', dateFromDB )
//=> 2005-12-03T18:30:00.000Z

console.log( 'Formatted Date:', formattedDate )
//=> 03/12/05
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.25.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var d = new Date('2005-12-03T18:30:00.000Z');

var date = d.getDate();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1; // Since getMonth() returns month from 0-11 not 1-12
var year = d.getFullYear();
var newDate = date + "/" + month + "/" + year;

console.log("Formatted Date:", newDate)
// Formatted Date: 3/12/2005
```

Answer (score 0):

So, that's format is called [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

```
'2005-12-03T18:30:00.000Z'
```

You can format it easily with a third-party library, I recommend to use **dayjs** it's lighter than moment

```js
dayjs('2005-12-03T18:30:00.000Z').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

more info, see: https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format